# Discord.js - Member Counter

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So,
what is up guys.

What im trying to do is pretty simple, but is still impossible for me.
I want to put the Membercount of a specific guild in my bots activity and rename a channel to the member count.

What i currently got is this:

```html
let category = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '777307358187618319'); 
let guild = bot.guilds.cache.find(server => server.id === '777307357934780426'); 
bot.user.setActivity(auf ${guild.memberCount} User., {type:'WATCHING'}); 
category.setName(☔「 COMMUNITY 」- User: ${guild.memberCount}).catch(console.error); 
console.log(update successful ${guild.memberCount});
```

The code seems to be working fine, when im starting the bot and run the command the first time, everything works, but after the membercount changes and im trying to use the command again, it still sets it to the old count.
Short: The bot saves the membercount on start, but doesnt really spit out the livecounter.

Might someone please help me out with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show errors that you have? Can you also move the code from the screenshots to code blocks?

Comment: @Snowy.dbf hey, im not getting any error.
i can give you the code here, sorry if it is not right, im new to this page:

  let category = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '777307358187618319');
  let guild = bot.guilds.cache.find(server => server.id === '777307357934780426');
  bot.user.setActivity(`auf ${guild.memberCount} User.`, {type:'WATCHING'});
  category.setName(`☔「 COMMUNITY 」- User: ${guild.memberCount}`).catch(console.error);
  console.log(`update successful ${guild.memberCount}`);

Comment: Please try to edit your question with any relevant code that you have in text form (not as screenshots, as you did). The information you provided is far too little to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: i have put it in, this is all the code required. @Xeoth

Comment: The rate limit for editing channel names/topics is 2 times per 10 minutes per channel. Maybe that's why things aren't working.

Comment: @Chiitoi this is unfortunatey not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code.
> 100% will work with you.

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
      setInterval(function() {
        // Important Variables
        let guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID_HERE")
        let channel = bot.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID_HERE")
        // Set Channel Name
        bot.setName(`☔ Members Count : ${guild.memberCount}`)
        // Set Bot Activity
        bot.user.setActivity(`☔ Guild Members : ${guild.memberCount}`, {
          type: "LISTENING" // client#Activity type
        })
      }, 30000) // this line will change bot activity and channel name every 30 seconds
    })
```

Comment: Well, thats pretty much the exact same code as mine. Still thanks :)